# Why Julia/JuliaDB behaves differently while filtering?

Tags: julia, juliadb

Executing

```
filter(i -> !ismissing(i.dep_delay > 60), select(flights, (:carrier, :dep_delay)))
```

should return the carriers with delay more than 60mins(my understanding!).  But it returns carriers with all positive and negative dep_delays.

Why it behaves so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you rather wanted to write:

```
filter(i -> coalesce(i.dep_delay > 60, false), select(flights, (:carrier, :dep_delay)))
```

If you write `!ismissing(i.dep_delay > 60)` you will get `true` if `i.dep_delay` is not `missing`.

Comment: sir, a short note on functionality of coalesce(), please!

Comment: It is a standard function in Base. If you look up its help you get: return the first value in the arguments which is not equal to `missing`, if any. Otherwise return `missing`. In a typical application (like the one you have) it is used to replace a `missing` with some value. So essentially `coalesce(v, v2)` is the same as `ismissing(v) ? v2 : v`. The difference is that `coalesce` can accept any number of arguments, but two-argument form is the most common.